# How much are you willing to pay for this treasure chest game?

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, expected-value

I was given an interesting problem that comes in two parts.

> In front of you is a treasure chest containing \$1000 with a 6-digit
>   combination lock. You have to pay a constant amount for each time you
>   change a digit. What is the maximum amount you are willing to pay per turn?

Not sure if my approach here is correct: if the expected value of the game is $E$ and the amount I pay per turn is $x$, then
$$E=\frac{1}{10^6}(1000-x)+\frac{10^6-1}{10^6}(E-x)$$
$$=E\left(1-\frac{1}{10^6}\right)+\frac{1000}{10^6}-x.$$
$$\Rightarrow E=1000-10^6x.$$
For positive payoff, we require $x<1000/10^6$, i.e. we want to pay less than \$0.001.

My main issue is with the next subproblem.

> When two or less digits are correct, an LED on the chest glows red.
>   When three or more (but not six) digits are correct, the LED glows
>   yellow. When all digits are correct, the LED glows green and the chest
>   opens. Is there an optimal strategy? How much are you willing to pay
>   per turn now?

How exactly do we form a strategy? I’m unsure of the most efficient way to keep track of the correct digits, and how to get back on track if a yellow LED switches to red. I am also unsure of how this affects the equation for the expectation. Could someone guide me on this please? Thank you!

Comment: How do you arrive at your equations?  For example, where does $6!$ come from?  Assuming there are 10 choices per digit, the number of possible codes is $10^6$.

Comment: @Michael oh silly me; will edit shortly!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1383971/mastermind-esque-safe-opening-problem/1391092#1391092 , One of the solutions is mine using Markov Chain method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- $\bf{\color{red}{\text{RED}}}$ is $0, 1, 2$ right digits
- $\bf{\color{orange}{\text{YELLOW}}}$ is for $3, 4, 5$ right digits
- $\bf{\color{green}{\text{GREEN}}}$ for the number itself
- $n = \overline{d_6d_5d_4d_3d_2d_1}$

Since nothing a priori is known, any first guess will work in the same way, we guess

> **$0-0-0-0-0-0$**

Few cases are possible (we don't know what is the case, except for color),

- $3$ to $5$ digits were guessed right. Then for every digit $d_1, \ldots, d_6$ try it(the digit) from $1$ to $9$, e.g. for $d_1$

  > $0-0-0-0-0-1$ to $0-0-0-0-0-9$ are tried

  if color changed (on the first try) to RED, we've initially guessed $3$ right digits, incl. $d_1=0$

  if color change to GREEN (during those 9 trials), we are done

  otherwise, inconclusive. Then proceed in the same way with other locations $d_2$ till $d_6$. If there were $3$ or $5$ correct digits initially, this will be established on those trials. We will need at worst all $54$ trials in case of $5$ (but we will learn the number), for $3$ after at most $28$ trials we will know it is $3$ and which digits are right (once you know it is $3$ - $1$ trial is enough to check every digit if it is right or not, still inside $28$).

  after $1 + 54$ trials, we established, there are $4$ right digits in $0-0-0-0-0-0$ guess. Now, pick a pair of digits, e.g. $d_1$ and $d_2$, and change them to $1-1$ (if color changed to RED - those were right digits, if to GREEN - done). In $3$ trials you find $2$ right zeros, in other $3$ the other right pair. In $18$ trials you can find the right value of two missing digits (you turn off two right, and run from $1$ to $9$ independently)

  in the same spirit you can establish in $27$ trials, all the digits, in case of $3$.

  check out, that initial testing could be done the triplets of digits [did not think this case for optimality].
- The more difficult is the case of RED light on $0-0-0-0-0-0$ trial.

  in $1000$ trials, trying all the triplets of $d_1, d_2, d_3$,  we can establish their true value, and from that point proceed like above [more $27$] - **this is the upper bound** on the number of trials

**The coverage idea**

is to try numbers, like in the kids game [have no idea of its English name]. Each number you try and get RED - you basically drop numbers, that would otherwise give you YELLOW or GREEN.

*Example*:

After we have tried $0-0-0-0-0-0$, we know that $n$ could not be $0, 1, 2, 10, 11, 999$, etc. In fact, **any** first try will eliminate $15850$ possibilities. Interestingly, guessing next $1-1-1-1-1-1$ will eliminate $15830$, etc. While, I'm yet to establish there are at most $100$ guesses, which eventually result in a YELLOW light.

**UPDATE** [31/07/2019]:
(After I have optimized code enough, so it will be solvable in the short - order of hours amount of time)

As I have stated previously, $1,000$ consecutive trials of $3$ right-most digits will hit every possible number with $\bf{\color{orange}{\text{YELLOW}}}$ light eventually.

Therefore we are interested in anything that is faster. I have applied a greedy algorithm, that traverses all the numbers and picks the number, that **covers** (i.e. turns light yellow) the most yet uncovered numbers. It is not the optimal (i.e. probably the list could be made short, by choosing some other numbers, or just by changing the order of numbers in coverage could lead to over *better* numbers to pick).

In the abstract land, build a graph on $1000000$ vertices. Define edges between two vertices $v$ and $u$, if the Hamming distance between their decimal representation is at least $3$. We want to find a dominating set in this graph. Such that, if we complete the dominating set, so we can move from one vertex in it to another (weights are just a Hamming distance), some Hamiltonian path through it has a minimal weight.

Unfortunately, I'm not that good in complexity, so I suppose both DS and HPP are hard problems.

In my attempt I have found a $292$ big dominating set. And finally iterated few times through it to find some Hamiltonian path with eventual weight of $949$ (i.e. $949$ digit changes, before you deterministically hit $\bf{\color{orange}{\text{YELLOW}}}$ light on any possible number, but without paying for the first attempt). Recall that after the yellow light was produced, it still could require another $54$ attempts to establish which digits are right (and the value of which were guessed wrong).

Overall, this strategy requires $949$ digit changes to hit yellow light, then $54$ (plus maybe $6$ to set the guessed digit to the wrong state and back in the final attempt). This is $1007$ attempts instead of at most $1026 = 999 + 27$ in the trivial strategy approach

Let call it $2 \text{%}$-better strategy.

Therefore, slightly less than $1\$$ is a safe point.

Dump of the coverage (i.e. combinations should be tried in this order):

> 231750
>
> 139790
>
> 159430
>
> 279637
>
> 257639
>
> 207536
>
> 923536
>
> 327580
>
> 370540
>
> 350948
>
> 351989
>
> 315189
>
> 815185
>
> 875104
>
> 951304
>
> 658394
>
> 738393
>
> 794593
>
> 595793
>
> 513593
>
> 413592
>
> 493997
>
> 491507
>
> 497605
>
> 293625
>
> 983655
>
> 981607
>
> 481403
>
> 441633
>
> 540634
>
> 520544
>
> 592542
>
> 256542
>
> 258112
>
> 554192
>
> 550722
>
> 91222
>
> 11762
>
> 13661
>
> 702661
>
> 302666
>
> 666666
>
> 626612
>
> 706319
>
> 806368
>
> 405328
>
> 55928
>
> 935920
>
> 845020
>
> 575080
>
> 215084
>
> 219046
>
> 209743
>
> 273443
>
> 663423
>
> 847423
>
> 857063
>
> 853253
>
> 103254
>
> 168154
>
> 148138
>
> 697138
>
> 617208
>
> 636203
>
> 349003
>
> 379906
>
> 272908
>
> 973418
>
> 912818
>
> 112806
>
> 112029
>
> 132098
>
> 178498
>
> 178649
>
> 78241
>
> 48521
>
> 388621
>
> 318652
>
> 218359
>
> 888379
>
> 843377
>
> 893747
>
> 890716
>
> 460386
>
> 970381
>
> 790281
>
> 395271
>
> 309275
>
> 304195
>
> 104110
>
> 605810
>
> 800
>
> 0
>
> 3008
>
> 69758
>
> 69370
>
> 69402
>
> 709102
>
> 725192
>
> 720693
>
> 120604
>
> 121325
>
> 107821
>
> 967824
>
> 147974
>
> 167987
>
> 987
>
> 54687
>
> 854517
>
> 862509
>
> 62589
>
> 23189
>
> 283188
>
> 888888
>
> 888565
>
> 180575
>
> 286574
>
> 886501
>
> 456701
>
> 426051
>
> 150051
>
> 870052
>
> 430852
>
> 464872
>
> 452870
>
> 472150
>
> 410137
>
> 230167
>
> 241107
>
> 241859
>
> 240898
>
> 910853
>
> 110913
>
> 582913
>
> 502483
>
> 922481
>
> 722088
>
> 751078
>
> 321076
>
> 341396
>
> 145796
>
> 945648
>
> 995663
>
> 175563
>
> 674523
>
> 671029
>
> 786029
>
> 786095
>
> 228091
>
> 236491
>
> 262591
>
> 662694
>
> 162711
>
> 111111
>
> 291311
>
> 194302
>
> 994709
>
> 999999
>
> 829399
>
> 429914
>
> 439518
>
> 336514
>
> 346785
>
> 749285
>
> 948282
>
> 946172
>
> 956476
>
> 952266
>
> 928760
>
> 124768
>
> 594678
>
> 534777
>
> 508737
>
> 501836
>
> 31835
>
> 34055
>
> 964015
>
> 904094
>
> 904931
>
> 714901
>
> 734956
>
> 24946
>
> 444444
>
> 408344
>
> 408265
>
> 468425
>
> 560465
>
> 566169
>
> 640169
>
> 680968
>
> 600778
>
> 600479
>
> 105459
>
> 187259
>
> 186247
>
> 537217
>
> 571297
>
> 861290
>
> 867450
>
> 687451
>
> 689031
>
> 685046
>
> 625366
>
> 625847
>
> 225875
>
> 227405
>
> 538805
>
> 597004
>
> 752014
>
> 642017
>
> 932077
>
> 832427
>
> 316427
>
> 320927
>
> 360228
>
> 764238
>
> 765432
>
> 742332
>
> 987312
>
> 87992
>
> 377932
>
> 379862
>
> 99867
>
> 91464
>
> 30234
>
> 35679
>
> 839671
>
> 884680
>
> 284360
>
> 383490
>
> 344458
>
> 526358
>
> 97356
>
> 692955
>
> 606155
>
> 659345
>
> 12345
>
> 16930
>
> 876935
>
> 801942
>
> 818446
>
> 728419
>
> 363819
>
> 333333
>
> 365307
>
> 755857
>
> 555555
>
> 909557
>
> 806684
>
> 814264
>
> 514239
>
> 437249
>
> 337141
>
> 737748
>
> 777777
>
> 773724
>
> 783844
>
> 796540
>
> 798120
>
> 753106
>
> 523200
>
> 222222
>
> 274216
>
> 774836
>
> 76896
>
> 196883
>
> 477883
>
> 499184
>
> 419626
>
> 589126
>
> 519374
>
> 613770
>
> 917795
>
> 71715
>
> 85213
>
> 22173
>
> 268973
>
> 648906
>
> 638586
>
> 631782
>
> 133062
>
> 563041
>
> 543961
>
> 547610
>
> 473675
>
> 485769
>
> 382734
>
> 824831
>
> 654891
>
> 711568
>
> 961143
>
> 498037

Answer (score 0):

This answer is limited to the first part of the problem, because there seems to be an error in the OP's approach there.

The OP's answer, $x\lt1000/10^6$ is correct only if there is a *single* attempt at unlocking the chest, or if by "willing to pay" what's meant is "willing to pay with no risk whatsoever of losing money."  If "willing to pay" has its more typical meaning of "willing to risk in order to get a positive expected return," and if you have *unlimited* attempts (and if you can keep track of the all those attempts, so you don't try the same combination twice), then the correct answer is $x\lt2000/10^6$ (or $1000/500{,}000$).

That is, if you systematically explore all $10^6=1{,}000{,}000$ different combinations without ever repeating yourself (which is possible to do while changing just one digit at a time), it'll take, on average, $500{,}000$ attempts to find the combination that unlocks the chest, so the expected return is $E=1000-500{,}000x$, and this is positive if $x\lt1000/500{,}000=\$0.002$ (i.e., two-tenths of a penny per attempt).

Comment: With every incorrect try you gain some information, so your argument is incorrect.

Comment: @pepster, I'm always willing, and sometimes even happy, to have a mistake pointed out, but I don't see one here. Could you please elaborate on what information is gained with each incorrect try in the setting for first part of the problem? (I totally agree that useful, nontrivial information is gained in the setting for the second part, as your answer lays out, but in the LEDless first part, the failure of one combination does not rule out anything but itself.)

Comment: See my answer below. Every unsuccessful try eliminates 15850 combinations:  all combinations which would gave yellow or green. For example, if you try 1,2,3,4,5,6 and get red, 1,2,3,X,X,X is not possible, 1,2,X,4,X,X not possible, etc. Not every guess reduces the total by that much, since some combinations might be already eliminated.

Comment: @pepster, as I tried to make clear, you are answering the *second* part of the OP's question, while I am only addressing the first part.  There are no lights in the first part of the question, so all you learn on each attempt is that that particular combination does not unlock the chest.

Answer (score 0):

(Only second part of the question. The first part seems trivial)

Short summary: it seems that a naive approach can find the combination in 200 tries (on average).

This problem can be thought of as a variant as the classic "bulls and cows" game, with the added restriction that a guess can differ by only one digit from the previous guess.

The optimal strategy is not obvious, but here is an observation and results from computer simulations.

Observation 1: after the LED turns yellow for the first time, you know one position for certain (the last one changed), and you can get the other two by turning the other five positions once or twice. If, after changing a digit, the LED stays yellow you keep the change. If it goes red you know the number for that position and you change it back. After determining those 3 change one of them to turn the led to red, and using at most 30 tries you can determine the values of the other 3.

Every time you make a change and the LED stays red you gain some information.  For example, if you try 1,2,3,4,5,6 and get red, 1,2,3,X,X,X is not possible, 1,2,X,4,X,X not possible, etc. At most you eliminate $15850 = 20 \cdot 9^3 + 15 \cdot 9^2 + 6 \cdot 9 + 1$ (first try, for instance), but in general some combinations might be rules out already, and in practice you eliminate 4,000 to 6,000 combinations in the first 50 moves or so.

I wrote some code which picks a guess by keeping track of all valid remaining combinations, picks a position in one valid combination which is different than the guess and changes the guess to match this value. This is obviously not optimal but can give an idea about the upper limits. It seems that this method can fine the combination in around 200 moves (on average).

The code is not fast, so I run only 20-30 times, but I think somewhere between 150 and 250 (for the average) is reasonable.

Finding a better strategy seems interesting but not trivial.

Comment: Observation 1 is only valid, if you change 1 digit at a time, which on average requires around 500 guesses to hit yellow.

Comment: This is the problem as stated, i.e. you pay for every digit change. I have no idea where this 500 comes from. Like I said, 200 seems closer to the truth.

Comment: Suppose the initial guess has no digit set right? How are you able to manage it in less than 500 guesses in expectation?

Comment: Edited my answer so the explanation might be clearer.